# Statistical texts

Tags: references, rule-of-thumb

Neophyte social science researcher here. I keep finding myself in the position of needing to reference the interpretation of some statistic or other (e.g. >.40 is adequate factor loading, >.80 is adequate Cronbach, a Heywood case indicates correlation greater than one, so the model is inappropriate, etc.). Am I better off looking for a good comprehensive statistical text that can be used as reference in manuscripts for a variety of purposes, or assembling a concise collection texts? Suggestions about approach and titles?

*edit: I am a doctoral student in social work. My purpose is to have stock references for common statistical benchmarks to include as citations in manuscripts. On several manuscripts I have been asked to give citations (for some of the things listed above, for example). These are things I learned in my statistics classes and from personal study, but don't necessarily have 'scholarly' references for -- e.g. part of the professors' lecture notes, but not discussed in the class text. 
Also, I am seeking to further my understandings. The class texts focused heavily on how to run various tests on SPSS, not so much on the mathematical underpinnings of the tests and statistics. As mentioned, most of my self-study has consisted of perusing online sources. Making a parallel to my self-study in algebraic number theory, getting pointed to a couple of good texts really helped me move along.

Comment: Which branch of social sciences?

Comment: Adequate for what purpose?

Comment: One problem is that many of these are myths. Nunnally and Bernstein is often citied as being the source of 0.7 being acceptable for coefficient alpha, but that is not what they say - it's more complex and nuanced. However, there's a book that might help you, called 'Statistical rules of thumb' by Philip Good.

Comment: @Jeremy Miles: I would avoid any book authored by Phillip Good

Comment: Perhaps @JeremyMiles meant SRoT by Gerald van Belle?